# Is there an idiom that means "we have a mutual understanding"?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom that means "we have a mutual understanding"? Or if there is not, is there an idiom that can be used to express a similar idea? I am pretty sure there are idioms or slangs that are often used to express such an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "a meeting of minds" indicates that two (or more) peopole have readed an understanding, usually an agreement. Indeed this is **the** standard phrase in contract law when people have understood each other and reached an agreement.

> They are on the same page.

Is significantly more informal, but generally means tha tthey have the same understanding of the subject.

> I want to make sure that we are on the same page.

means "I want to be sure tht we fully understand each other and agree."

Comment: If two people agree completely about something, we can say they see (or are) "eye to eye" on that topic.